# How should I edit my /etc/network/interfaces entry for both ipv4 and ipv6?

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, ipv6, ipv4

I have an entry for my PC's Ethernet adapter in `/etc/network/interfaces`; say that it's:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.123/24
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
```

and this has been working nicely for me for a long time. Now, my ISP is giving my router an IPv6 address, and I also seem to be getting an IPv6 address if I use a DHCP client on my PC:

```
   inet6 [snip]:[snip]:[snip]:[snip]:[snip]:[snip]:[snip]:[snip]/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr 
       valid_lft 171220sec preferred_lft 171220sec
   inet6 [snip]::[snip]:[snip]:[snip]:[snip]/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

(instead of the snips, I have quadruplets of hexadecimal digits.)

Now, I want to set up my `interfaces` file entry to reflect this. Specifically, I *think* I need to set up a token, which later on is supposed to help me somehow with configuring dynamic DNS. I've seen this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/616856/how-do-i-add-an-additional-ipv6-address-to-etc-network-interfaces

for example, but it's about IPv6-only settings.

PS - In case it matters, I use Devuan Daedalus.